# how to get the largest value from the second column for vlookup value in first column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A B
5 25
4 10
3 15
5 100

in this case i want to vlookup the **"5"** from **column A** & answer would be **100**

```
=+VLOOKUP("5",A:B,2,FALSE)
```

which give me 25

Answer (score 1):

Use array formulas.  For example, assuming your numbers above are in **A2:B5**, type the following within a single cell, and press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**:

```
=MAX(IF(A2:A5=5,B2:B5,-1000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

**VLOOKUP** only allows you to lookup the first occurence.

Your best option is to filter the table used for **VLOOKUP** to order from largest to smallest based on that second column. This will force the first instance of **lookup_value** in **VLOOKUP** to be next to the highest value of that entry. The below duplicates of **lookup_value** all have lower column two values and hence will not be seen by **VLOOKUP** as the highest entries are pushed to the top.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this also

=SUMPRODUCT((LARGE(IF(A2:A5=5,B2:B5,""),1)))

**Press Ctrl + Shift + Enter.**